# Spark SQL Correlated scalar sub-queries can only be used in a Filter/Aggregate/Project

Tags: apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am trying to join tow streaming data in Spark structured streaming. Data structures are as follows:

Table: CardHolder

| CardNo | AssignTime | Assignee |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2023 01:00:00 | user 1 |
| 1 | 01/01/2023 01:00:05 | user 2 |
| 1 | 01/01/2023 01:00:10 | user 3 |

Table: CardTransaction

| CardNo | TransactionTime | Transaction |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2023 01:00:00 | transaction 1 |
| 1 | 01/01/2023 01:00:10 | transaction 2 |
| 1 | 01/01/2023 01:00:03 | transaction 3 |
| 1 | 01/01/2023 01:00:07 | transaction 4 |
| 1 | 01/01/2023 01:00:12 | transaction 5 |

Those two data should be joined into this data:
Table: CardTransactionFlow

| CardNo | TransactionTime | Transaction | Assignee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2023 01:00:00 | transaction 1 | user 1 |
| 1 | 01/01/2023 01:00:10 | transaction 2 | user 3 |
| 1 | 01/01/2023 01:00:03 | transaction 3 | user 1 |
| 1 | 01/01/2023 01:00:07 | transaction 4 | user 2 |
| 1 | 01/01/2023 01:00:12 | transaction 5 | user 3 |

The issue is that `TransactionTime` in `CardTransaction` table should match with the latest `AssignTime` in `CardHolder` table before `transactionTime` for earch transaction record. To archive this i tried to use `max(assignTime)` function but i can not get it to work. Spark throws `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Correlated scalar sub-queries can only be used in a Filter/Aggregate/Project and a few commands: Join LeftOuter`. Watermark ise set on date columns.

```
  select 
    holder.cardNo,
    trx.transactionTime,
    trx.transaction,
    holder.assignee,
    from transaction trx LEFT OUTER JOIN holder holder ON 
    trx.cardNo=holder.cardNo AND 
    holder.assignTime = (select max(assignTime) from holder 
        where trx.cardNo=cardNo AND assignTime <= trx.transactionTime) + interval 1 minute
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the lead functnion for the df1 to get the time range and join with df2.

```
data1 = [
    [1, '01/01/2023 01:00:00', 'user 1'],
    [1, '01/01/2023 01:00:05', 'user 2'],
    [1, '01/01/2023 01:00:10', 'user 3']
]
data2 = [
    [1, '01/01/2023 01:00:00', 'transaction 1'],
    [1, '01/01/2023 01:00:10', 'transaction 2'],
    [1, '01/01/2023 01:00:03', 'transaction 3'],
    [1, '01/01/2023 01:00:07', 'transaction 4'],
    [1, '01/01/2023 01:00:12', 'transaction 5']
]

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data1, ['CardNo', 'AssignTime', 'Assignee']).withColumn('AssignTime', f.to_timestamp('AssignTime', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss'))
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data2, ['CardNo', 'TransactionTime', 'Transaction']).withColumn('TransactionTime', f.to_timestamp('TransactionTime', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss'))

df1.printSchema()
w = Window.partitionBy('CardNo').orderBy('AssignTime')

df3 = df1.withColumn('AssignTimeAfter', f.lead('AssignTime', 1, '2999-12-31 23:59:59').over(w))
df3.show()

df2.alias('a') \
  .join(df3.alias('b'), (f.col('a.CardNo') == f.col('b.CardNo')) & (f.col('a.TransactionTime') >= f.col('b.AssignTime')) & (f.col('a.TransactionTime') < f.col('b.AssignTimeAfter')), 'left') \
  .select('a.*', 'b.Assignee') \
  .show()

root
 |-- CardNo: long (nullable = true)
 |-- AssignTime: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- Assignee: string (nullable = true)

+------+-------------------+--------+-------------------+
|CardNo|         AssignTime|Assignee|    AssignTimeAfter|
+------+-------------------+--------+-------------------+
|     1|2023-01-01 01:00:00|  user 1|2023-01-01 01:00:05|
|     1|2023-01-01 01:00:05|  user 2|2023-01-01 01:00:10|
|     1|2023-01-01 01:00:10|  user 3|2999-12-31 23:59:59|
+------+-------------------+--------+-------------------+

+------+-------------------+-------------+--------+
|CardNo|    TransactionTime|  Transaction|Assignee|
+------+-------------------+-------------+--------+
|     1|2023-01-01 01:00:00|transaction 1|  user 1|
|     1|2023-01-01 01:00:10|transaction 2|  user 3|
|     1|2023-01-01 01:00:03|transaction 3|  user 1|
|     1|2023-01-01 01:00:07|transaction 4|  user 2|
|     1|2023-01-01 01:00:12|transaction 5|  user 3|
+------+-------------------+-------------+--------+
```