# spark sql left join with comparison in subquery

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

question updated on Feb 20th:

I have the following 2 dataframes:

df_a:

| id | date | code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-06-27 | A |
| 1 | 2021-12-27 | A |
| 2 | 2021-12-27 | A |
| 3 | 2022-03-21 | A |
| 3 | 2022-08-01 | A |

df_b:

| id | date | code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-05-19 | A |
| 1 | 2021-05-31 | B |
| 1 | 2021-08-27 | C |
| 3 | 2021-11-06 | X |
| 3 | 2022-02-15 | Y |
| 3 | 2022-12-30 | Z |

expected result:

| id | date | code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-06-27 | B |
| 1 | 2021-12-27 | C |
| 2 | 2021-12-27 | A |
| 3 | 2022-03-21 | Y |
| 3 | 2022-08-01 | Y |

I want to use df_b.code to update df_a.code by the following condition:

use the row from df_b where b.date is latest prior to the df_a.date.

I tried:

```
select a.id, b.code
from df_a left outer join df_b
on a.id = b.id
and b.date = (select max(b.date) from df_b where id = a.id and date <= a.date)
```

but I'm getting 'Correlated scalar sub-queries can only be used in a Filter/Aggregate/Project and a few commands' error

Comment: Can you add the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the exact question and with the correct answer here:
[Spark SQL Correlated scalar sub-queries can only be used in a Filter/Aggregate/Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75294311/spark-sql-correlated-scalar-sub-queries-can-only-be-used-in-a-filter-aggregate-p)

It worked for my case.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

win = Window.partitionBy(df_a.id).orderBy(df_b.date.desc())
(
    df_a
    .join(df_b,['id'])
    .filter(df_a.date > df_b.date)
    .withColumn("r", F.row_number().over(win))
    .filter(F.col("r")==1)
    .select(df_a.id, df_a.date, df_b.code)
).show()
```

Output:

```
| id|      date|code|
+---+----------+----+
|  1|2021-06-27|   B|
+---+----------+----+
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the input, I tried this one, but the line '.filter(df_a.date > df_b.date)' will filter out all other records except for the matching one. even if I put 'left outer' in your script, it still give me just one record from df_a that exist in df_b

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is, get the lead date for the df1 first and join with between.

```
data1 = [[1, '2021-06-27', 'A']]
data2 = [[1, '2021-05-19', 'A'], [1, '2021-05-31', 'B'], [1, '2021-08-27', 'C']]
cols = ['id', 'date', 'code']

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data1, cols).withColumn('date', f.col('date').cast('date'))
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data2, cols).withColumn('date', f.col('date').cast('date'))

w = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('date')

df3 = df2.withColumn('date_after', f.lead('date', 1, '2999-12-31').over(w))
df3.show()

df1.alias('a') \
  .join(df3.alias('b'), (f.col('a.id') == f.col('b.id')) & (f.col('a.date').between(f.col('b.date'), f.col('b.date_after'))), 'left') \
  .withColumn('new_code', f.coalesce('b.code', 'a.code')) \
  .select('a.id', 'a.date', 'new_code').toDF('id', 'date', 'code') \
  .show()

+---+----------+----+----------+
| id|      date|code|date_after|
+---+----------+----+----------+
|  1|2021-05-19|   A|2021-05-31|
|  1|2021-05-31|   B|2021-08-27|
|  1|2021-08-27|   C|2999-12-31|
+---+----------+----+----------+

+---+----------+----+
| id|      date|code|
+---+----------+----+
|  1|2021-06-27|   B|
+---+----------+----+
```